# What is the search scope of CDI in case of injectable bean lookup?

Tags: cdi, weld

I have a multi module maven project (a Java EE app with ear, persistence, web, ejb, api, bl and other modules), where I'd like to use Weld CDI.

When I try to inject a bean, where will Weld search for injectable beans? Will Weld search in all the modules, where a beans.xml is placed to WEB-INF or META-INF regardless from their dependencies (or dependencies matter somehow?), or will Weld be able to inject a bean from an other deployment? I tried to find a document, which describes the mechanism and boundaries of bean lookup, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is part of the overall EE spec, not the CDI spec.  but yes, in general the contents of your EAR will be discovered as distinct applications (per the EE spec).  This means that you may not be able to access individual beans across JARs.  It is highly recommended to use WAR deployment with CDI.